# Arraylist doubled in jtable display

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

New to java. 
So, here's my code. Whenever I click on add button, it will also add the previous data I added.

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

        coffee coff = new coffee(name.getText(),coffeeName.getText(),Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()),buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand(),(Integer)quanOrder.getValue());

        coffeeArray.add(coff);

        for(int i = 0; i < coffeeArray.size(); i++)
        {
           String customerName = coffeeArray.get(i).getName();
           String cofName = coffeeArray.get(i).getCoffeeName();
           int price = coffeeArray.get(i).getuPrice();
           String OrderMode= coffeeArray.get(i).isOrderMode();
           int quantity = coffeeArray.get(i).getQuanOrder();

           Object[] rowCoffee = {customerName,cofName,price,OrderMode,quantity};

           model.addRow(rowCoffee);
        }
```

Comment: Soooo... What's the question?

Comment: How to fix it... I enter the details - then add for the first time (it works fine). But if I add another, in my jtable it displays the previous data and then the recent.

Comment: I don't see you setting the table model? sure you get it but I'm pretty sure that would just be value based returned not reference.

Comment: How to fix what? What do you expect this code to do and what is this code doing?

Comment: I enter the details - then add for the first time (it works fine). But if I add another, in my jtable it displays the previous data and then the recent.

Comment: The problem is you are adding things that are already in the model. Instead of doing that, you can either clear the model before going through the for loop, or instead of adding everything in the `ArrayList`, you can just add the one coffee. By the way, the common convention for Java Classes is to start with a capital letter, so `coffee` class should be `Coffee` instead, but that isn't an actual problem and just helps with readability

Comment: yeah. fixed. ha'to remove loop though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions,

First solution, just add the object you are wanting to add to the model:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

    coffee coff = new coffee(name.getText(),coffeeName.getText(),Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()),buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand(),(Integer)quanOrder.getValue());

    coffeeArray.add(coff);

    //Instead of going through the for loop, adding objects you already have, just add the one you just added to the model.

    model.addRow( new Object[] {coff.getName(), coff.getCoffeeName(), coff.getuPrice(), coff.isOrderMode(), coff.getQuanOrdered() } );
```

Second solution, remove all tables from the model, then go through the for loop:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

    coffee coff = new coffee(name.getText(),coffeeName.getText(),Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()),buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand(),(Integer)quanOrder.getValue());

    coffeeArray.add(coff);

    //Remove all rows before adding everything from ArrayList.
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
        model.removeRow(i);

    for(int i = 0; i < coffeeArray.size(); i++)
    {
       String customerName = coffeeArray.get(i).getName();
       String cofName = coffeeArray.get(i).getCoffeeName();
       int price = coffeeArray.get(i).getuPrice();
       String OrderMode= coffeeArray.get(i).isOrderMode();
       int quantity = coffeeArray.get(i).getQuanOrder();

       Object[] rowCoffee = {customerName,cofName,price,OrderMode,quantity};

       model.addRow(rowCoffee);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add a new coffee (seriously a lowercase class name?) in the line  `coffeeArray.add(coff);` you cycle ALL the array coffeeArray and add each coffee element to the table.
You are adding all the array each time, so the first time you add the 1st element, the second time you're adding the 1st and the 2nd, the third time you are adding the 1st, 2nd and 3rd and so on so forth.
Consider adding to the table only the new coffee and not the entire array:

```
coffeeArray.add(coff); 
Object[] rowCoffee = {coff.getName(),coff.getCoffeeName(),coff.getPrice(),coff.isOrderMode(),coff.getQuanOrder()};
model.addRow(rowCoffee);
```

Comment: class name changed (thanks)